# Ramsey counter examples

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I do not know of any solution or if it's an open problem: Let $R(i,i)=k$, therefore there exists a counter examples with blue and red edges for a clique of size $k-1$. Does there exist a counter-example for $k-1$ nodes with an almost equal number of red and blue edges (any bound is welcome). Even more interesting: Is there a counter-example with a not almost equal number of red and blue edges for $k-1$ nodes? Define almost equal number however you want, I am interested in any result.

As a user suggested in the comments, I am also interested in Ramsey numbers on any graph, not just Ki

Comment: Interesting. I guess you could ask the same question about the generalized Ramsey numbers $R(G,G)$ where $G$ is a graph, not necessarily complete. At least there would be some examples to look at, since quite of few exact Ramsey numbers are known for sparse graphs.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea, would it be okay to edit that into my question?

Comment: Yes, why don't you do that.

Answer (score 0):

$K_9$ cannot be decomposed into two planar graphs.

[image: K_8 decomposed into planar graphs]

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question in any way. What am I missing?

Comment: I guess that's pretty cool, but not quite what I'm after